# How to insert multiple value in vector in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to know that is there any way that we can insert a multiple values in a vector as a single value without using a temp variable?

I mean for example:

```
struct Something{
    int x;
    int y;
};
int main()
{  
    vector <Something> v;
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    v.push_back(x, y);
}
```

Is there any way that we avoid doing this(defining another variable, then inserting that, instead of insert `x, y` directly):

```
Something temp;
temp.x = x;
temp.y = y;
v.push_back(temp);
```

Comment: v.push_back(create_something(x,y)) ?

Comment: The code will be shorter and more clear, in my idea. If there isn't any logical and acceptable method, You can say, it's impossible!

Comment: @MiladR: Sorry, I had misunderstood; never mind!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Give your class a constructor, like this:

```
Something(int x_, int y_) :x(x_), y(y_) {}
```

Then you can just do this:

```
v.push_back(Something(x,y));
```

In C++11, you can do this, without the constructor:

```
v.push_back({x,y});
```

Comment: In C++11, one can write `v.push_back({x,y})` and no constructor needed.

Comment: @Nawaz: Yep.  I was testing that because I wasn't 100% positive.

Answer (score 8):

In C++11, you can use emplacement functions:

```
if (std::cin >> x >> y)
{
    v.emplace_back(x, y);
}
else { /* error */ }
```

This assumes that your `Something` class has an `(int, int)` constructor. Otherwise you can use `push_back` with a brace initializer, as in Benjamin's answer. (Both versions are probably going to produce identical code when run through a clever compiler, and you may like to keep your class as an aggregate.)

Comment: ok! I try this and I didn't get error! But is there any command in terminal or something that can tell me the version of my C++ compiler?I know it's g++ only and I am on ubuntu!

Comment: @MiladR: Use this : `gcc --version`. It will tell you the version you're using.

Comment: @MiladR: You can get your compiler version with the `-v` option.  See [this table](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) to see if your version supports the C++11 feature you require.  I believe GCC 4.4 supports everything that's been suggested.  You just need to pass the `-std=c++0x` option to use those features.

Answer (score 7):

In C++11, you can do this:

```
v.push_back({1,2});
```

You don't need to write a constructor as suggested by other answer.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work in C++11 Visual Studio 2012 unless you have manually downloaded and updated to the Beta version. Currently it is not in it's final release, but a few months from now it will probably be working with an auto update.