# How to push_back multiple values into a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, std

I know this question has been asked before, and I know that in C++11 you can do

```
vector<int> v = {2,5,8,11,14};
vector<int> v{2,5,8,11,14};
```

and

```
v.push_back({x,y});
```

But it gives me a compile error. I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012.

How do I accomplish this?

EDIT: error screenshot attached:

[image]

Comment: *"But it gives me a compile error. "* Always add the error message.

Comment: Note that your question title is inconsistent with your question.

Comment: You cannot do `v.push_back({x,y});` in C++11.

Comment: @juanchopanza Are you sure? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741194/how-to-insert-multiple-value-in-vector-in-c

Comment: I am sure. That question does not deal with an `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Wow, that syntax is really confusing! I hope it will never be used for anything other than vector <int>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 [does not support vector initialization via initializer lists](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/20708516-9192-436d-9545-1f85db10405d/uniform-initializer-support-in-vs-2012). There is a lot of C++11 support missing from the standard library included with VS2012 that is supported by the VS2012 C++ compiler itself.

Sadly, as is the case for VS2012 and was the case for gcc 4.7, awesome compiler support for the new C++11 features is hampered by partial library support which seems to always lag behind the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Until you have a compiler that can support vector initializer lists you can use [boost::assign::list_of](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using this compiler and it's standard libraries, as previously stated by @Michael Goldshteyn can't be done. But if You're willing to include boost libraries, You can use code like this:

```
#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp>

using namespace boost::assign;

{
    std::vector< int > myElements;
    myElements += 1,2,3,4,5;
}
```